# Wrong encoding of non-English String

Tags: java, character-encoding, stream, internationalization

I am trying to send a message that contains English and Russian text, but the Russian text is displayed as "?? ???????"

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
writer.println("English" + "На русском");
writer.flush();
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I do not see anything being printed there.  I see something being sent to some "clientSocket" which you have shown us nothing about.  So, there is not enough information to have reasons to believe that this is an IntelliJ IDEA issue. What happens if you just do `System.out.println( "На русском" );` ?

Comment: When I simply type System.out.println( "На русском" ); - I see right symbols in the console. But when I try to send the message over the web - I get ???? symbols.

Comment: what do you mean "send the message over the web"? your writing the output through a servlet?

Comment: Exactly. Through a servlet.

Answer (score 1):

So, your problem was has nothing to do with IntelliJ IDEA.

The `PrintWriter` constructor that only accepts an `OutputStream` creates a `PrintWriter` that makes use of the default character encoding of the JVM.  You can check what the default character encoding of the JVM is by invoking `Charset.defaultCharset()`.  However, you should not rely on it having any particular value, either at the sending end, or at the receiving end. It is best to either set the default character encoding of the JVM, or to supply a specific character encoding when creating your `PrintWriter`.  The following should do it:

```
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter( outputStream, charset );
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( osw ) );
```

If you are in control of both the sending side and the receiving side, then you may have to add the corresponding on the other side with the `Charset` of the `InputStream`.

Comment: Thanks! It works. But for now when I try to accept the message by BufferedReader - I get the same unknown symbols (without the code you suggested I could write and read Russian symbols in the chat). Should I encode BufferedReader too? Can you please write how to implement it?

Comment: You would use something like `try( Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) ) { ...`